# Send SMS to each contact in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite table that has different phone numbers and different messages for each. I want to get the ID for each row so that my IntentService can send the unique SMS to each number.
This is what I have done:

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {
public NotificationService() {
    super(NotificationService.class.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String number = extras.getString(String.valueOf(MessageContract.MessageEntry.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER));
        String message = extras.getString(String.valueOf(MessageContract.MessageEntry.COLUMN_CODE));
        sendMessage(number, message);
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String number, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

}
```

This is my Contract class

```
public final class MessageContract {

private MessageContract() {}

public static class MessageEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "message";
    public static final String COLUMN_CODE = "code";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER = "phoneNumber";
}
}
```

Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Cursor cursor = database.getSavedNumbers();
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
  {
do 
  { 
  String message = cursor.getString(0);//Column Message should be on 0th position 
  String number = cursor.getString(1);//Column Number should be on 1st Position
  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
}while(cursor.hasNext());
}

cursor.close();
```

Comment: `Cursor` must be closed :)

Comment: Thank you. I get an error for hasNext() and getSavedNumber()